# Read failed error while wallet transfer

Tags: wallet.dat, dogecoin

I run ubuntu 12.04 and had to reinstall the OS so I copied wallet.dat and saved them into another computer, now that I am done installing the OS and then installed dogecoind and replaced wallet.dat file but it says

```
message":"ReserveKeyFromKeyPool() : read failed"}
```

Comment: Do you get that on startup or running a command?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because my blockchain was not synchronized, I waited for it to sync and then repeated the process and it worked